# Error in invocation of runtime.sendMessage (Chrome API)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The goal is to send a message to a content script from a background script after a URL is changed.

Here is my function:

```
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
      function (tabId, changeInfo, tab){
        if(changeInfo.url && changeInfo.url.includes('https://example')){  
             chrome.runtime.sendMessage(tabId, {warn: 'message'}, function(resp){})
    }
});
```

But I get an error: Error, in event handler: TypeError: Error in invocation of runtime.sendMessage(optional string extensionId, any message, optional object options, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'options': Unexpected property: 'warn'.

I tried to code according to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/), but can't find the error

Comment: Replace `runtime` with `tabs`.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks a lot for your help! I think I will have new questions in future for you:)

Answer (score 3):

I was getting a similar error until I did something like

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {warn: 'message'});
```

Note: tabs, not runtime method.
I had to leave out the message parameter. Not sure about callback.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding some information about what went wrong here:

This is for messaging to the background script.

> chrome.runtime.sendMessage

This is for messaging to any content script in your tabs.

> chrome.tabs.sendMessage

Their parameters are also slightly different, as mentioned in other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the API wrong. sendMessage should receive two parameters. The first one can be an object and the second one would be a callback with the response. This way:

```
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {
      message: "this is a message",
    },
    (response) => {
      // ... do something with the response
    }
  );
```